# Why doesn't the "and" condition work in my Python codes?

Tags: python, logic

Each separate statement is true, but why is the combination of the two with "and" false?
[codes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w79vp.png)

Comment: The priority of `&` is greater than `==`.

Comment: In your next question please provide your code as text, not as a screenshot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In python and is a logical AND that returns True if both the operands are true whereas ‘&’ is a bitwise operator. I think you are trying to to something like this.

```py
if (other_list[0] == 0 and rand_vec[0] == 1):
    # Do something
```

Comment: Can you paste your code?

Answer (score 0):

Many thanks to Pw Wolf and all others! Now I understand it.

Original code:

```
if (other_list[0] == 0 & rand_vec[0] == 1):

    # do something
```

Improved code:

```
if (other_list[0] == 0 and rand_vec[0] == 1):

    # do something
```